# Get the name of the HTML document that called a JS function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a beginner with JS.
I am working with some JavaScript on a site, and I just want to use only 1 file of JS for determine the actions off the pages. Something like this:

```
function registerEvents(){
     NameOfHTMLDocument = //?? Get the name of the document that called registerEvents function.
  switch(NameOfHTMLDocument)
  {
    case:"homepage":
          hmp_btn = document.getElementById("hmp_btn");
          hmp_btn.onclick=otherFunction;
          break;
    case:"otherPage":
          elem = document.getElementById("elemID");
          elem.onclick=fooFunction;
          break;
     //etc...
 }
}
```

This function is called with a `<body onload="registerEvents()">` that is "inherited" by all the pages.

The question is, How can I get the "NameOfHTMLDocument"?. Because I don't want that JS begin doing weird things when trying to get elements that don't exist.

I found that I can get the URL of the DOM and then play a little with it to get the string that i want, but i'm not sure if this is the better way of doing it.

It Would be nice if you have a better suggestion.

Comment: You want to get the URL of the of the page calling the function?

Comment: I was trying to avoid use the URL , to get this you can use: location.pathname.split('/').pop(); and you will get an array of strings and "play" a little with it.OR get a document.URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly I would really suggest that you create separate script tags in html documents for functionality that  is used only on that page and common functionality in separate file for several reasons:

- No code pollution
- Ease of change
- Smaller download

Secondly, you can use switch on window.location.pathname DOM variable which is everything after domain
instead of homepage, etc..

i.e.

url = vader.samplesite.com/light/saber/

window.location.pathname = /light/saber/

(look at http://www.developertutorials.com/questions/question/q-242.php )

Answer (score 1):

```
window.location.pathname
```

All you need to do is some parsing, but I'm sure you'll figure that out :) If not, leave a comment.

Answer (score 1):

In your `<body onload="registerEvents()">` pass the object this (the BODY in the DOM) through your event function such as : `<body onload="registerEvents( THIS )">`.

In your function itself, call the object you passed like `object.ownerDocument.URL` to get the URL including the HMTL document name or `object.ownerDocument.title` to get the page title.